# Download user generated data from Wordpress

Tags: database, ios

I have created a Wordpress site which I allow users to enter information about themselves such as name, age, sex and address etc.

Now that I have this n formation I would like to know the steps I should use to download all of the information from all registered users on my site using an objective c NSURLConnection library.

I know how to use NSURLconnection, I am used to doing a query where the information is returned in xml or Json format.. However I don't know how to interface this request on my server? For instance do I create a php file that dose the query for me? Or something else?

Ay help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way I read that, you're looking for some sort of API access to your WordPress site. I don't know enough about it, but XML-RPC support does exist, perhaps that would get you pointed in the right direction. There is a JSON REST API in development that will become part of the core WP - there is also a JSON REST API plugin that might give you what you need. Good luck.

Comment: Oay thanks, I will investigate that and post any. Findings here.